# How do I make a placeholder file on github?

Tags: javascript, html, css, github, placeholder

How do I create placeholder files for CSS, Javascript and HTML file on a **project** in GitHub? 
How do I create that project too? 
(GitHub and coding newbie here)

Comment: Do you understand git?

Comment: Your question is far too broad and under-researched. "Creating a new project on Github" and "Adding an empty file to a Git repository" are completely different problems, both of which should be trivial to learn how to do (Github has some fairly obvious buttons, and adding files to a repo is covered by any introductory git tutorial) without asking Stackoverflow to explain them to you.

Comment: Ever visited Github?

Comment: There's a big button on github which says "new repository". As for placeholder files, I don't see the need for them... can you explain?

Comment: Does an achievement exist for the maximum number of down votes? The question sounds like a good idea to get it.

Comment: SORRY guys I did try to research online I couldn't find it.
To create a new project you just go to the projects tab which I hadn't seen before. I thought you had to add a new file or something. 
No I don't understand git lol I'm trying to follow these instructions to create something as part of a club (its to teach amateurs like me how to code). Thats why I need to create the placeholder files for a project (what are placeholder files..? I swear I researched this but I didn't find much)

Answer (score 2):

If you're referring to files that you want to commit to your repository, but not share with others, a .env file is a good example of this, you should ignore your local file by adding it to your .gitignore file, and then create a copy with placeholder text and append .example to the file name.

.gitignore

```
.env
```

file structure

```
/
|-.git/
|-.gitignore
|-.env
|-.env.example
|-everything else
```

Answer (score -2):

Search for the following strings on Github:

- New repository
- Initialize this repository with a README
- Create repository
- Create new file

After that switch to Youtube and search for "zappa bobby brown". And wait for the last sentence after the song.